# Sort according to enum order

Tags: java, sorting, enums

I have a enum that looks like this in java.

```
public enum Fruit {

Apple,
Banana,
Orange,
Pineapple,
Grape,
Pear
}
```

And I have a list that contains these fruits unsorted.
The is the list:

```
List<Fruit> fruits= Arrays.asList(Pineapple, Banana,Orange, Grape, Apple, Banana, Apple);
```

Now I want to sort it so it sorted  like this:

Apple,
Banana,
Orange,
Pineapple,
Grape,
Apple,
Banana

Tried with collections sort but it is not working. How can I sort in this order?

Comment: By what logic do Apple and Banana not group with their duplicates in your example of desired output?

Answer (score 2):

This reads like subset (hope this is the correct description) problem. While there is a total set of (Pineapple, Banana,Orange, Grape, Apple, Banana, Apple), there are two distinct subsets, a = (Pineapple, Banana, Orange, Grape, Apple) and b = (Banana, Apple).

I would handle them as such, create a list of sets (here a hashset) and collect fruits until the current set encounters a fruit it already knows, then create a new set and collect further. Repeat this until you all fruits are collected.

Then sort each set separately and aggregate all sets into a final list of all fruits.

```
List<Fruit> fruits = Arrays.asList(Pineapple, Banana, Orange, Grape, Apple, Banana, Apple);
    List<Set<Fruit>> toSort = new ArrayList<>(); //list of sets
    Set<Fruit> set = null; //the current set

    for(Fruit fruit: fruits) {
        //if current set is empty or the fruit is already in the set, then create a new set for the current fruit and proceed
        if(set == null || !set.add(fruit)) {
            toSort.add(new HashSet<>());
            set = toSort.get(toSort.size() -1);
            set.add(fruit);
        }
    }

    //iterate over all sets, map them to a list, sort the list and combine all lists into a final single list
    List<Fruit> sortedFruits = toSort.stream().map(s -> s.stream().toList().stream().sorted().toList()).flatMap(List::stream).toList();
    System.out.println(sortedFruits);
```

This would give you [Apple, Banana, Orange, Pineapple, Grape, Apple, Banana].

**Edit 1**

This

```
List<Fruit> sortedFruits = toSort.stream().map(s -> s.stream().toList().stream().sorted().toList()).flatMap(List::stream).toList();
```

should be this (redundant stream/toList)

```
List<Fruit> sortedFruits = toSort.stream().map(s -> s.stream().sorted().toList()).flatMap(List::stream).toList();
```

**Edit 2**

As *rzwitserloot* pointed out, memory could be an issue, so instead of collecting everything in a different list we could also directly sort into a new list. Not a huge improvement, but more readable.
So here is the changed code:

```
    private static void sortFruits() {
    List<Fruit> fruits = Arrays.asList(Pineapple, Banana, Orange, Grape, Apple, Banana, Apple);
    List<Fruit> fruitsSorted = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Fruit> set = new HashSet<>();

    for(Fruit fruit: fruits) {
        if(!set.add(fruit)) {
            set.stream().sorted().forEach(fruitsSorted::add);
            set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add(fruit);
        }
    }

    set.stream().sorted().forEach(fruitsSorted::add);
    System.out.println(fruitsSorted);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Tried with collections sort but it is not working. How can I sort in this order?

That's not possible. `Collections.sort` can only be used to sort things in certain kinds of orders. Your desired sorting order doesn't have these kinds of properties. Specifically, these things work by telling the sort code which of any 2 members of your input list comes before the other, and that is **not** something you can do with what you want (Does 'Apple' sort before or after 'Banana'? There is no answer to that. The first 'Apple' sorts before the first 'Banana', but the second apple sorts after the first banana. The index isn't part of this getup).

You have a few options.

### Map, sort, map

You could first create a completely different list that *does* have the property that it can be sorted with a 'which one of these 2 is higher' oracle, then sort it, then map it back to what you want.

I **can** sort a list of objects that consist of both the enum value *and* the occurrence count. Say, I have this class:

```
class FruitCount {
  Fruit fruit;
  int counter;
}
```

And you have a list: `[(Apple, 0), (Apple, 1), (Banana 0), (Grape 0), (Banana 1)]` - that can be sorted with `Collections.sort`. To determine which of 2 such things are 'earlier': The one with the lower counter always comes first. If they have the same counter, the one with the lower `.ordinal()` value of the enum comes first. Simple.

Thus, the exercise boils down to a few mostly unrelated parts. That's generally how programming goes: You break it down into simpler tasks.

1. Create a type that represents fruit + counter.
2. Write code that turns a list of fruit values into a list of FruitCount objects.
3. Write code that sorts a list of FruitCount.
4. Write code that turns a list of FruitCount objects back into just a list of Fruits.

### Forget sort

Write it yourself. The general algorithm is to continually loop through your enums, and add each enum value to the output list as long as there's at least one such value in your input list. If yes, remove one such value from the input and add to the output. if not, skip it. Once the input list is empty, you're done.

This is simpler, but less efficient. Unless your input is millions of fruits, I wouldn't worry about the efficiency, though.

Looks a bit like:

```
var out = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
while (!input.isEmpty()) {
  for (Fruit f : Fruit.values()) {
    if (input.remove(f)) out.add(f);
  }
}
```